# A diagonal in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

A convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ with sides $AB=8$ cm, $BC=16$ cm, $CD=4$ cm and $AD=6$ cm is given. Find the diagonal $BD$ if the length is an integer.

[image]

Comment: Have you made an attempt at solving this?

Comment: Okay.  I'll do this.  What will you be doing while I do this?

Comment: I use Triangle inequalities, but not sure about result.

Comment: pretty pictures don't compensate for lack of effort/context/attempts, etc.

Comment: @amWhy: the poster is telling that he worked around triangle inequalities. Does not seem to me that this post deserves to be put on hold more than many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality on $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$: a triangle exists with sides $a,b,c$ if and only if $a+b>c$, and cyclic permutations thereof. $6+8>BD$, $16>4+BD$. Wasn't that hard, was it?

Comment: So is $ABCD$ is convex, $BD=13$ is the only possible integer value of $BD$. But why is it really attained by some configuration? Sorry for the nitpicking, but I guess it might be useful to state it clearly. (+1) by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put
$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to   = {\bf a}} & {\left| {\bf a} \right| = 8}  \cr 
   {\mathop {BC}\limits^ \to   = {\bf b}} & {\left| {\bf b} \right| = 16}  \cr 
   {\mathop {CD}\limits^ \to   = {\bf c}} & {\left| {\bf c} \right| = 4}  \cr 
   {\mathop {DA}\limits^ \to   = {\bf d}} & {\left| {\bf d} \right| = 6}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
by which
$$
{\bf a + b + c + d} = {\bf 0}
$$

Now we have that the diagonal equals
$$
diag = \mathop {BD}\limits^ \to   =  - {\bf a} - {\bf d = c} + {\bf b}
$$
so that for its modulus we will have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right|^{\,2}  = \left| {\bf a} \right|^{\,2}  + \left| {\bf d} \right|^{\,2}  + 2{\bf a} \cdot {\bf d} = \left| {\bf c} \right|^{\,2}  + \left| {\bf b} \right|^{\,2}  + 2{\bf c} \cdot {\bf b} =   \cr 
  &  = 100 + 2{\bf a} \cdot {\bf d} = 272 + 2{\bf c} \cdot {\bf b} =   \cr 
  &  = 100 + 2\left| {\bf a} \right|\left| {\bf d} \right|\cos \alpha  = 272 + 2\left| {\bf c} \right|\left| {\bf b} \right|\cos \beta  =   \cr 
  &  = 100 + 96\cos \alpha  = 272 + 128\cos \beta  \cr} 
$$

Note that the angle $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors $\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to $ and $\mathop {DA}\limits^ \to$,
and therefore it is supplementary to the internal angle in $A$, and analogously for the angle $\beta$.

Since the cosine varies between $-1$ and $1$ we shall have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  100 - 96 \le \left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right|^{\,2}  \le 100 + 96 \hfill \cr 
  272 - 128 \le \left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right|^{\,2}  \le 272 + 128 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 144 \le \left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right|^{\,2}  \le 196\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 12 \le \left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right| \le 14 \cr} 
$$

Therefore we get the following possible results

> $$
> \matrix{
>    {\left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right| = 12} & {\cos \alpha  = 44/96} & {\cos \beta  =  - 1}  \cr 
>    {\left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right| = 13} & {\cos \alpha  = 69/96} & {\cos \beta  =  - 103/128}  \cr 
>    {\left| {\mathop {BD}\limits^ \to  } \right| = 14} & {\cos \alpha  = 1} & {\cos \beta  =  - 76/128}  \cr 
>  } 
> $$